Access to fetch at *** from origin *** has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - Microsoft ADFS with Django
I am trying to integrate Auth ADFS with Django App and Angular and I keep getting CORS error.
I tried everything but nothing seems to be working.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your-tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={your-client-id}&response_type=token&redirect_uri={your-redirect-uri}=openid' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/api/base/login/') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My setting.py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'base_app',
    'django_crontab',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'customer_account',
    'upload_data',
    'project',
    'django_auth_adfs',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_auth_adfs.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
         'django_auth_adfs.rest_framework.AdfsAccessTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    # 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    #     'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser'
    # ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),

    # 'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'rest_framework.views.exception_handler'
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'utils.exceptionhandler.custom_exception_handler'


}


CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = default_headers + (
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
)

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'GET',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
    'PATCH',
    'DELETE',
    'OPTIONS',
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

......
AUTH_ADFS = {
    'AUDIENCE': CLIENT_ID,
    'CLIENT_ID': CLIENT_ID,
    'CLIENT_SECRET': CLIENT_SECRET,
    'CLAIM_MAPPING': {
                    #     'first_name': 'given_name',
                    #   'last_name': 'family_name',
                      'email': 'upn',
                      },
    'GROUPS_CLAIM': 'roles',
    'MIRROR_GROUPS': True,
    'USERNAME_CLAIM': 'upn',
    'TENANT_ID': TENANT_ID,
    'RELYING_PARTY_ID': CLIENT_ID,
}



Django API:

@api_view(['GET'])
def loginAPI(request):
    return JsonResponse({"message": "Login Page Successful"})

Angular Function:
export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit {
  private apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/base/loginAPI'; // Make sure this URL is correct
  data: any;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private http: HttpClient, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.redirectToApi();
    }
  }

  redirectToApi() {
    this.http.get(this.apiUrl).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.data = response;
        console.log(this.data);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    );
  }
}


Postman Test:
The API http://127.0.0.1:8000/base/loginAPI works fine when tested via Postman.
What I've Tried:
Configured CORS settings in settings.py as shown above.
Made sure the middleware is set up correctly.
Verified that the API works in Postman.
Despite these efforts, I still encounter the CORS error. Any help on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Have you tried configuring CORS in ADFS?
The link is here.

Do I also need to do CORS configuration for Azure Active Directory?
Is the CORS error due to the fact that Authentication is provided to the backend and the Frontend is not authorized to access Backend App?

In AAD, CORS depends on the feature e.g. CORS for storage - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services
